# How can I fix "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref" when implementing an iterator that returns mutable references?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a mutable iterator for a linked list called `Thread` where each element implements `Block`.

```
trait Block<'a> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)> {
        None
    }
}

pub struct Thread<'a> {
    head: Box<dyn Block<'a> + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Thread<'a> {
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> ThreadIterator<'a> {
        ThreadIterator {
            next: Some(self.head.as_mut()),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ThreadIterator<'a> {
    next: Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ThreadIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)> {
        self.next.take().map(|mut block| {
            self.next = block.next();
            block
        })
    }
}
```

Compiling this will output the error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:14:34
   |
14 |             next: Some(self.head.as_mut()),
   |                                  ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 12:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> ThreadIterator<'a> {
13 | |         ThreadIterator {
14 | |             next: Some(self.head.as_mut()),
15 | |         }
16 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:14:24
   |
14 |             next: Some(self.head.as_mut()),
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 11:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl<'a> Thread<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:14:24
   |
14 |             next: Some(self.head.as_mut()),
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `dyn Block<'_>`
              found `dyn Block<'a>`
```

This is why I need the `'a` requirement for all `Block`s (they are borrowing a `Runtime`):

```
struct Runtime {}

struct ExampleBlock<'a> {
    runtime: &'a Runtime,
    next: Box<dyn Block<'a> + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Block<'a> for ExampleBlock<'a> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)> {
        Some(self.next.as_mut())
    }
}
```

The first thing I tried was removing the mutable requirement from all references. Same errors.

I think the error is telling me that `self.head.as_mut()` is outliving `self.head`, so I must ensure that the lifetime of that reference is shorter than `Thread<'a>`. I thought I fulfilled this requirement with the `'a` lifetime for `ThreadIterator<'a>`. In other words, you can't possibly drop `Thread` before `ThreadIterator`, right?

Edit:

I changed `Block` to a struct to simplify the code, though I need it to be a trait in the end.

```
struct Block {}

impl<'a> Block {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Block> {
        None
    }
}

pub struct Thread {
    head: Block,
}

impl<'a> Thread {
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> ThreadIterator<'a> {
        ThreadIterator {
            next: Some(&mut self.head),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ThreadIterator<'a> {
    next: Option<&'a mut Block>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ThreadIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut Block;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Block> {
        self.next.take().map(|mut block| {
            self.next = block.next();
            block
        })
    }
}
```

It is based off of https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-iter-mut.html.

The answer to [`cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements` but can't change anything due to trait definition constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847200/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicting-requirement) was to introduce a `Option` for the iterator, which I have done. [Lifetime parameter problem in custom iterator over mutable references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361624/lifetime-parameter-problem-in-custom-iterator-over-mutable-references) and [Reimplementation of LinkedList: IterMut not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320262/reimplementation-of-linkedlist-itermut-not-compiling) didn't answer my question, though I have a hard time connecting my code to theirs.

I finally found something that does work:

```
pub struct Block {}

impl<'a> Block {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Block> {
        None
    }
}

pub struct Thread {
    head: Block,
}

impl Thread {
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> ThreadIterator<'_> { // The lifetime here is changed
        ThreadIterator {
            next: Some(&mut self.head),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ThreadIterator<'a> {
    next: Option<&'a mut Block>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ThreadIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut Block;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Block> {
        self.next.take().map(|mut block| {
            self.next = block.next();
            block
        })
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time applying this to the original code, because there might be two different lifetimes, one for the iterator and one for the trait.

Comment: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [`cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements` but can't change anything due to trait definition constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61847200/155423); [Lifetime parameter problem in custom iterator over mutable references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62361624/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Reimplementation of LinkedList: IterMut not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35320262/155423)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [u/quixotrykd/](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/hzhd3d/need_help_with_figuring_out_lifetimes_in_my/fziz9tv/):

The compiler seems to be choking here because it doesn't know how the lifetime on `&mut self` and `ThreadIterator` relate. As such, it has no way to guarantee that `&mut self` lives at least as long as the underlying borrow in `ThreadIterator`. Looking at your code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a119b1136d0696267373fed49ac3d9c2), that would be line 12 (note I've fixed your mistake in the above link).

You need to tell the compiler that the lifetime on the output `ThreadIterator` is the same as the input `&mut self` (or technically that it lasts at least as long, though you very likely want the same lifetime here), otherwise the compiler has no way to ensure that the "self" that's borrowed by `&mut self` stick around as long as the `ThreadIterator`'s borrow. Looking at the rules for lifetime elision [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html), we can see that this doesn't apply to your code, and as such, you need to manually specify the lifetime on `&mut self` (otherwise it generates another, unrelated, anonymous lifetime, as indicated in the compiler's error message).

The fixed code:

```
pub trait Block<'a> { // Make public to resolve unrelated error
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)> {
        None
    }
}

pub struct Thread<'a> {
    head: Box<dyn Block<'a> + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Thread<'a> {
    fn iter_mut(&'a mut self) -> ThreadIterator<'a> { // Add lifetime to &self
        ThreadIterator {
            next: Some(self.head.as_mut()),
        }
    }
}

pub struct ThreadIterator<'a> {
    next: Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ThreadIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut (dyn Block<'a> + 'a)> {
        self.next.take().map(|mut block| {
            self.next = block.next();
            block
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution still resulted in various other errors in my project so I ended up using `Rc<RefCell<...>>`. Way easier to use.